# Bash commands that work on an iphone

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, bash

I've jailbroken my phone, and I'd like to execute some commands on it from my phone, namely, the Say command. That, unfortunately, does not work. What commands COULD I execute on the iphone, other than the standard `ls` and `cd`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For an exhaustive list, you can simply do ls for all of the directories in the shell's `$PATH` variable--that's what the shell uses to search for a command when you type it.

```
ls ${PATH//:/ }
```

The above runs `ls` using the path variable as an argument, but with the `$PATH`'s usual `:` separators replaced by a space.

Comment: It returned: -sh: PATH//:/: No such file or directory.

Comment: Are you sure you're using curly braces `{}` and not parentheses `()`?

Comment: @NReilingh This is probably the greatest thing I've learned all month.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of command-line tools available for jailbroken iOS, many of them [ported by saurik](http://www.saurik.com/id/1). If you want to find more than come with the default Cydia installation, first check Manage -> Settings (button at top left) to make sure you have your "Who Are You?" category set to *Hacker* or *Developer*. Then go to Manage -> Sources -> Cydia/Telesphoreo and browse around.

You can also install "BigBoss Recommended Tools" to install a large list of these at once.

Comment: Do you know of any packages that might contain the "say" command or any repos that might have that package? And if not, would this merit it's own question? I'm on the verge of getting downvoted into "questions unaccepted" mode.

Comment: I don't know of any; ["say" seems to be proprietary Apple software](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/say.1.html), so somebody would have to do a lot of work to replicate it. Telesphoreo includes [Festival-Lite](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/flite/), but it makes wav files instead of playing audio.